# Joomla | How to filter input string containing html tags

Tags: php, joomla

I have a joomla component and trying to filter HTML content from the users input.

```
$input  = $app->input->post->getRaw('question');
```

This will getting me the RAW html.

How can I check (The joomla way or custom php function) is it safe before saving into my database?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this for a custom component you are building?  If so, are you using xml form definition files loaded in into a JForm object and binded to a cooresponding JTable object?  If so, then Joomla already does all that for you automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla has an automatic function for that, please check `System -> Global Configuration -> Text Filters` and set the appropriate filtering for your user group.

If you want to do that with php, you could use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function. Your result would be like:

```
$input  = strip_tags($app->input->post->getRaw('question'));
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the input to a string, striping all HTML tags/attributes, this way:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$input = $jinput->get('question', 'default_value', 'html');
```

Official Documentation: [Retrieving request data using JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput)